# Blazor server side project keeps disconnecting from server

Tags: azure-devops, blazor-server-side

I have an server side Blazor application, which is deployed to Azure and I have turned on websocket toggle button as well in Azure,
My application keeps disconnecting to server in inconsistent interval (After inactivity from user upto 1.5hrs to 8hrs) is there a way to fix this and why the disconnection time is inconsistent ?

[Web socket button in Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYbHW.png)